# Reverse a payment

Tags: payment

Posted the wrong amount to an event and would like to go back and fix. Not sure how to reverse the payment or just delete it.

Thanks,

Alex Englander

Comment: Is it a online payment or recorded offline?

Answer (score 1):

In case of data entry error - I recommend you delete and recreate. Otherwise you’ll end up with additonal financial transactions that could be negative (looks like you ‘refunded’) or positive (looks like you received an ‘additional payment’).